# Pre-2000 Ranma 1/2 and Sailor Moon fanfic with a failed romance between Michiru and Ranma

Tags: story-identification, fan-fiction, crossovers, ranma-one-half, sailor-moon

Seeing if anyone can find a fanfic where there was a crossover between Ranma 1/2 and Sailor Moon, where (pre-series) Michiru and (post-series) Ranma where the plot brought them together in a relationship somehow, but they couldn't make the relationship work, so they broke up on good terms. Good enough terms that Ranma's there to give a "shovel speech" to Haruka when she and Michiru get together, that went something like:

> "I'm not gonna beat around the bush. You break up? Fine. You hurt her? I'm gonna kick your ass, then your balls, until you beg for mercy which I won't give you. Got it?"
>
> "...I'm a girl."
>
> "You've seen my curse. I got some fun powder..."

Fanfiction.net doesn't hold any fanfic older than the 2000s.

[Apparently](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/160730/42059) there's a site called [The Eyrie](https://archives.eyrie.org/anime/Ranma/?C=M;O=A) with bunches of Ranma 1/2 fanfics gzipped", [another answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/174120/42059) pointed me to "thekeep.com", but that times out for me, and the [Fanfiction Mailing List](https://www.fanfics.dev/) doesn't seem to have anything, given my searches for "Haruka", "balls" and "powder".

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you'd quoted my post. [The Eyrie](https://archives.eyrie.org/anime/Ranma/?C=M;O=A) is where I downloaded the fanfics.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Thanks! Only Bing seems to have indexed it, and still no good results with said terms of "Haruka" + "powder" or "fun powder".

Comment: FWIW, I think the method I used before was to download all of the gzipped files, extract them to a directory so that I'd have text files, then use the file search of Notepad++ to look for the keywords. It _is_ a few extra steps, admittedly.

Also, you can probably use the Wayback Machine at archive.org to access TheKeep.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Yeah, the Web Archive has The Keep, but where's its fanfic directory and stuff? The main page seems to be military-style fanfiction? http://web.archive.org/web/20170226153944/http://www.thekeep.org

Comment: Huh. It had been a while since I had last visited. If you still have the URL of the author that you are looking at, You can find the pages, for example https://web.archive.org/web/20080211001517/http://www.thekeep.org/~rpm/ranma/ has a series that I was looking for. Kind of vexing that they don't link to that from the main page though.

Comment: I downloaded all of the fics and did some keyword searches, but no dice on anything that quite sounds like your dialog.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - I assume you mean The Eyrie? Thanks!